# COMException when in-app purchase

Tags: c#, silverlight

I set up a button to call following method:

```
private async void buyTimeUP()
{
    await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("MyItem", false);
    DoFullFillment();
}
```

when I buy/download this item, everything is fine and the following code runs just fine:

```
public void DoFullFillment()
{
    var productLicenses = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses;
    checkTransaction(productLicenses["MyItem"]);
}

private void checkTransaction(ProductLicense lic)
{
     if (lic.IsConsumable && lic.IsActive)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine("License bought");
         CurrentApp.ReportProductFulfillment(lic.ProductId);
      }
}
```

But if the user returns from the in-app dialog with the back-button or if he cancels the transaction, the code crashes at

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyApp.Shop.<buyTimeUP>d__0.MoveNext()
```

How can I get rid of this bug?

Answer (score 0):

to fix this add try/catch around RequestProductPurchaseAsync method call...

```
try
{
   receipt = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync("MyItem", false);
}
catch (Exception){}
```